# Ignored List has "St", "Li", "pre" using autocomplete functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I should remove the list of words "St", "Pair", "Bri"  using automplete functionality.

```js
var igonoredWords = [
  "st ",
  "Pair",
  "Bri",
  "Elem",
  "stu"
];

$(".myInput").keyup(function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  if (text.indexOf(igonoredWords) == -1 && text.indexOf(igonoredWords) == -1) {
    $(".myInput").autocomplete({
      source: data.text
    });
  } else {
    $(".myInput").autocomplete("destroy");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='myInput' type='text'>
```

Please help on this.

Comment: You're missing a comma in your array declaration. Even when that's fixed you get a 'data is undefined' error. It's also not clear what your goal is

Comment: didn't understand your requirement

Comment: I have updated code with comma, problem is  I need a solution for how to ignore few words when typing autocomplete search box.

Comment: I just provided sample code, but I am not sure, how to ignore words

Comment: Don't know what the autocomplete stuff does, but the search thing looks strange. Just tried a snippet like this:                    
  $(".myInput").keyup(function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  if(igonoredWords.includes(text)){  
 console.log(text + " found in ingnoredWords");
  }
});

Comment: what is data.text?

Comment: autocomplete function means, when we are typing any key on text box, it will show related stuff. like ex: If I search key word is "N" , then search results show on dropdown like newton, newyork.. etc. So same thing I should restrict when typing few words, like ex: If type "pre" keyword on textbox, then it should be ignored, no results found. this type of functionality I should implement on this.